Why does my grouped array sometimes generate incorrect data for specific fields inside Foreach?
I have a Laravel function that processes an array of delivery items and groups them by DeliveryID to create a structured array of deliveries. Each delivery includes details such as items, subtotal, and an extra_fields URL generated using the DeliveryID. However, I'm encountering an issue where the extra_fields URL sometimes includes an incorrect DeliveryID.
Here is the function:
public function getDeliveries($delivery_items)
{
    $deliveries = [];

    foreach ($delivery_items as $delivery_item) {
        if (isset($deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID])) {
            $items = $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['items'];
            $subtotal = $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal'];
        } else {
            $delivery_array = [
                'cust_ref' => $delivery_item->DeliveryID,
                'ship_first_name' => $delivery_item->Delivery_First_Name,
                'ship_last_name' => $delivery_item->Delivery_Last_Name,
                'ship_address_1' => $delivery_item->Delivery_Address_1,
                'ship_address_2' => $delivery_item->Delivery_Address_2,
                'ship_city' => $delivery_item->Delivery_City,
                'ship_state' => $delivery_item->Delivery_State,
                'ship_zip' => $delivery_item->Delivery_Zipcode
            ];

            if ($this->hasExtraField($delivery_item)) {
                $order_id = $delivery_item->DeliveryID;
                $limited_scope_key = config("services.example_api.key");
                $delivery_array['extra_fields']['api_link'] = "https://api.example.com/orders/{$order_id }";
            }

            $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID] = $delivery_array;

            $items = [];
            $subtotal = 0;
        }

        $items[] = [
            'item_no' => $delivery_item->ItemID,
            'item' => $delivery_item->Item_Number,
            'description' => $delivery_item->Item_Description,
            'price' => $delivery_item->Item_Price,
            'quantity' => $delivery_item->Item_Quantity
        ];

        $subtotal += $delivery_item->Item_Total;

        $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['items'] = $items;
        $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal'] = $subtotal;
        $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['grand_total'] = $subtotal;
    }

    return $deliveries;
}

What could cause the extra_fields URL to include an incorrect DeliveryID? Is there a better way to prevent this from happening?

Seems overly complex, what you are doing there. You shouldn't need to check if $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID] already exists first - PHP allows you to ad new entries to an existing array, at every level / depths, without complaining. So just do $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['items‘][] = [/*item data*/];

And summing up the subtotal doesn't require using extra variables either. $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal'] = ($deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal'] ?? 0) + $delivery_item->Item_Total; will do. (Assuming your PHP version supports the ?? operator already. If not, use $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal'] = (isset($deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal']) ? $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal'] : 0) + $delivery_item->Item_Total;)

Not sure what the purpose of $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['grand_total'] is supposed to be, when you are assigning the exact same value as for $deliveries[$delivery_item->DeliveryID]['subtotal']?

@C3roe already doing that. subtotal/grand total doesn't matter. it's not issue. issue is in extra field.

What could cause the extra_fields URL to include an incorrect DeliveryID?
$order_id in extra_field is mismatching DeliveryID sometimes. only sometimes. This is issue.

Hard to tell, without knowing your actual data model, and no sample data. Unclear, for which order items hasExtraField returns true, whether that's all of then, or just some of them, and if just some, then which ones ...

hasExtraField is only for some.  i.e. $delivery_item->ship_state==FL

And would that always be the first one, within a group within the same delivery ID ...? If not, your code will stay in the if branch for that item, and therefor not handle the extra field at all.
